# Hooks when a member is moved to another member group

Tags: hook

Is there a hook in ExpressionEngine that triggers when any one member is moved from group to another?

Answer (score 2):

As Derek said, there isn't a hook for member group change, but you could accomplish this by using the two member update hooks provided by the [Member Model](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/member_model/index.html#member-model-extension-hooks) in conjunction with the [Cache Access provided by the Session Class](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html#cache-access).

**Hook 1: [member_update_start](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/member_model/index.html#member-update-start)**
In your method called by this hook store the member's existing group_id using the [Session Class `set_cache()` method.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html#Session%3a%3aset_cache)

**Hook 2: [member_update_end](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/member_model/index.html#member-update-end)**
In your method called by this hook retrieve the existing group_id (set above) by using the [Session Class `cache()` method](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html#Session%3a%3acache) and compare it to the updated group_id to see if it has changed.

This works well in my quick test.

Comment: +1 - i guess you mean member_id and **group_id**

Comment: Ah, yes, that's what I meant. I updated my answer to correct this. Thanks!

Comment: Of note on this (clever) solution: it will only work when changing member groups via the CP - those hooks won't fire when changing member groups programatically.

Comment: Derek, why not fire the hooks in your own code too :-) (i have the same problem with hooks not firing with the auto_expire extension, which just bluntly updates table where expire_date < now. Just add some hooks yourself) [Hook, don't hack (MadeByHippo)](http://www.madebyhippo.com/blog/view/expressionengine_hook_dont_hack)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Best you could do is run a cron job which replicates the `exp_members` table periodically, then compares it to the real table, and takes action on any members whose groups affiliations have changed.